# request.url is giving me example.com/login instead of example.com/feed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails 4.2.2

If I click on the link:

```
<%= link_to "Feed", feed_path, data: {turbolinks: false } %>
```

or paste the url

```
www.example.com/feed
```

A `before_action` in my `UsersController` redirects to the `login_url`

```
Application Controlller
def logged_in_user
  unless logged_in?
    store_location
    flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
    redirect_to login_url
  end
end

module SessionsHelper
def store_location
  session[:forwarding_url] = request.url if request.get?
end

def redirect_or
  redirect_to(session[:forwarding_url] || root_url)
  session.delete(:forwarding_url)
end
```

After successfully logging in, the `redirect_or` method is redirecting me back to the login_url.

`request.url` is being saved as www.example.com/login

Comment: Does your login_url call store_location, too?

Comment: It looks like you are using code from the RailsTutorial. So your `SessionsController` should look like [this?](https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_rails_4/blob/master/app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb#L10). Does your line 10 use `redirect_or` (it's `redirect_back_or`) in the linked example? If not, this should be the cause of your problem.

Comment: I am using redirect_or in Sessionscontroller. That is not the problem.

Comment: You didn't add `store_location` to the `login_url` [after this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41367946/request-url-is-giving-me-example-com-login-instead-of-example-com-feed#comment69937702_41367946) did you? If you did you are overwriting `store_location` with the `login_url` after the `redirect_to login_url`... which you don't want to do. If *that* is no the issue I would add `puts` in `store_location` before and after `session[:forwarding_url]` because I don't think it's getting saved properly.

Comment: @BigRon okay, i figured it out. i have a modal that will render the login form and i call <% store_location %> in the modal which was what was triggering it. you can submit your above comment an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't add `store_location` to the `login_url` [after this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41367946/request-url-is-giving-me-example-com-login-instead-of-example-com-feed?noredirect=1#comment69937702_41367946) did you?

If you did you are overwriting `store_location` with the `login_url` after the `redirect_to login_url`... which you don't want to do.

If that is not the issue I would add `puts` in `store_location` before and after `session[:forwarding_url]` because I don't think it's getting saved properly.

**[Nice work debugging this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41367946/request-url-is-giving-me-example-com-login-instead-of-example-com-feed?noredirect=1#comment69941780_41367946)**